# How can I use strcmp() correctly in this code?

Tags: c++, string, strcmp

I want to compare `cs[i][a].days[x]` and `"Mon"` in order to find out if I can put this string into Monday's catalog...
But it seems like it does not work? (No matching functions )

```
#include <iostream>
  #include <string>
  #include <cstring>
    struct course{
        string name;
        string *days; //dynamic array of days int start_hr, start_min;
        int start_hr, start_min;
        int end_hr, end_min;
    };
            void print_day2(course **cs,int num, int number, int day){
                    cout << "Monday: " << endl;
                    for(int i = 0; i <number; i++){
                        for(int a = 0; a < num;a++){
                            for(int x = 0; x < day; x++){
                                if(strcmp(cs[i][a].days[x], "Mon")==0){
                                    cout << cs[i][a].days[x] <<endl;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: In addition to using `operator==` to compare strings, consider using `std::vector<std::string>` for your `days` member.

Answer (score 3):

While it is tempting to call `->c_str()` to do a C style compare using `strcmp`, it is better to just use `->compare()` or simply `==` as they are more native C++ idioms

C style (*not recommended*):

```
strcmp (cs[i][a].days[x].c_str(), "Mon")
```

Member function:

```
cs[i][a].days[x].compare("Mon")
```

relatational operator

```
cs[i][a].days[x] == "Mon"
```

Note that this will not convert `"Mon"` to a `string` because both `->compare()` and `==` have an override for `const char *`.

Comment: `"Mon"` is not converted to a `std::string` because `basic_string` has an [operator== overload for array of charT](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp)

Comment: @RedX thanks, no idea why I missed the overrides, updated to note this

Comment: @AURRR is there anything else you need to have you accept this answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use c_str() to convert your string to a C string(null terminated)